# Need help creating method to return position of a number in an integer

Tags: java, indexing

I'm working on a game called "Cows and Bulls". Basically, this is a number guessing game where player one picks a random, distinct 4-digit number, and player two tries to guess the number.

For example,

-Player one picks the random number: 1465
-Player two guesses the number: 6432. Since the number player two guesses shares a common number (6), this number has one "Cow". A "Cow" is when the number player two guesses shares a common number with the random number player one picks, but it's not in the same place (the 6 is the first digit in player 2's number, whereas it's the third in player 1's number.)

-If Player two guesses the number: 1466, there is 1 "Cow" and 3 "bulls". A "Bull" is when the number Player two guesses shares a common number(s) with Player 1's, AND it is in the same place.

My problem is, I need to make a method that returns the position of a number in an integer.

For example, if I have an integer "1456", I need a method that tells me what position (from the right) any given number is. So if I want to know where the number "5" is, it would tell me "2" because it is second from the right. If I wanted to know where "1" is, it would tell me "4" because it is fourth from the right.

I **cannot** use any of the built in java string methods.

Below is what I have wrote so far, it's not organized at all as I am still working on it.

This method has to call to the methods "numDigits" and "getDigit", thats why I left them in the code. "numDigits" returns the number of digits in a number. "getDigit" returns what number is in a particular position. So, if I have a number "12345", getDigit will return "2" if I input "4" because "2" is fourth from the right in the number.

You can see I started "indexOf" at the bottom of my code.

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough, I'm new to Java so I don.t know the best way to explain everything.

```
package pa3;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CowsAndBulls {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Welcome to Cows and Bulls Game. I picked a random 4-digit number with distinct integers, try finding it. Type your guess, must be a 4-digit number with distinct digits.");
        //System.out.println(numDigits(12346));
        System.out.println(getDigit(12345, 5));
        System.out.println(hasDistinctDigits(1234));
    }
    public static int numDigits(int number)
    {
        {

            int counter = 0;

            while(number > 0)
            {
            number = number/10;
            counter++;
            }

            return counter;
            }
    }


        public static int getDigit(int number, int i)
        {
            {
                int digit = 0;

                if (i <= numDigits(number))
                {
                    while (i > 0)
                    {
                         digit = number % 10;
                        number = number / 10;
                            i--;
                    }
                }
                return digit; }
        }






        public static boolean hasDistinctDigits(int number)
        {
            if(getDigit(number, 1) != getDigit(number, 2) &&
              getDigit(number, 1) != getDigit(number, 3) &&
              getDigit(number, 1) != getDigit(number, 4) &&
              getDigit(number, 2) != getDigit(number, 3) &&
              getDigit(number, 2) != getDigit(number, 4) &&
              getDigit(number, 3) != getDigit(number, 4))
              {
                  return true;
              }
              else return false;

            }

        public static int generateSecretNumber()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int randNum = r.nextInt(9999);

            while (hasDistinctDigits(randNum) = true)
                {       
                        randNum = r.nextInt();  
                        return randNum;

                }

        }
        public static void indexOf(int number, int digit)
        {

        }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just use your two methods and iterate through the number:

```
 public static int indexOf(int number, int digit)
 {
    int count = numDigits(number);
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        if(digit == getDigit(number, i))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  //the digit was not found
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the input as String, not as number / Integer.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String player1 = "1465"; // solution
        String player2 = "6431"; // guess

        Integer cows = 0, bulls = 0, k;

        for (int i = 0, j = player2.length(); i < j; i++)
        {
            Character ch = player2.charAt(i);
            String s = ch.toString();

            if (player1.length() > i && player1.charAt(i) == ch) {
                bulls++;
            }
            else if (0 <= (k = player1.indexOf(s))) {
                cows++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("BULLS: " + Integer.toString(bulls));
        System.out.println("COWS:  " + Integer.toString(cows));
    }
}
```

[Run this code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/s6rh51)